# How can a parent class determine which type was passed to a method, based on the subclass?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create subclasses to handle permissions for different areas of an app. Each subclass has a different list of valid actions that they handle, along with various reasons we show if the action is not allowed. I'm trying to define a `hasPermissions` method on the parent class to check if a permission is enabled, but I want it to complain if I pass in a string that is not a valid action for the current instance.

I know I can handle this by defining `hasPermissions` on each subclass, i.e. `hasPermissions (actionName: UserActions) { ... }`, but I'm hoping to avoid this. Is there a way the parent class can determine which actions are allowed, based on the the current instance?

```
declare var _;

type TPermission<TAction, TReason> = {
    action: TAction;
    enabled: boolean;
    reason?: TReason;
}

class Permissions {
    constructor(protected permissions) {
    }

    hasPermission(actionName) {
        let permission = _.find(this.permissions, {
            action: actionName
        });

        return permission ? permission.enabled : false;
    }
}

type AdminActions = 'Add User' | 'Delete User';
type AdminReasons = 'MaxUsersReached' | 'CantDeleteAnotherAdmin';
type TAdminPermission = TPermission<AdminActions, AdminReasons>;

class AdminPermissions extends Permissions {
    protected permissions: TAdminPermission[];

    constructor(permissions: TAdminPermission[]) {
        super(permissions);
    }
}

type UserActions = 'Subscribe' | 'Unsubscribe';
type UserReasons = 'AlreadySubscribed' | 'AlreadyUnsubscribed';
type TUserPermission = TPermission<UserActions, UserReasons>;

class UserPermissions extends Permissions {
    protected permissions: TUserPermission[];

    constructor(permissions: TUserPermission[]) {
        super(permissions);
    }
}

let permissions: TUserPermission[] = [
    {
        action: 'Subscribe',
        enabled: true
    }
];

let user = new UserPermissions(permissions);

user.hasPermission('Subscribe'); // Valid, should return true
user.hasPermission('Unsubscribe'); // Valid, should return false
user.hasPermission('Add User'); // Invalid permission for UserPermissions, should error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the parent class generic:

```
class Permissions<T extends string> {
    ...

    hasPermission(actionName: T) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And then:

```
class AdminPermissions extends Permissions<AdminActions> { ... }

class UserPermissions extends Permissions<UserActions> { ... }
```

Then the compiler will complain about this:

```
user.hasPermission('Add User');
```

Saying:

> Argument of type '"Add User"' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'UserActions'

As you wanted.

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=declare%20var%20_%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20TPermission%3CTAction%2C%20TReason%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20action%3A%20TAction%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20enabled%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20reason%3F%3A%20TReason%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Permissions%3CT%20extends%20string%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(protected%20permissions)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20hasPermission(actionName%3A%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20permission%20%3D%20_.find(this.permissions%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20action%3A%20actionName%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20permission%20%3F%20permission.enabled%20%3A%20false%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20AdminActions%20%3D%20'Add%20User'%20%7C%20'Delete%20User'%3B%0D%0Atype%20AdminReasons%20%3D%20'MaxUsersReached'%20%7C%20'CantDeleteAnotherAdmin'%3B%0D%0Atype%20TAdminPermission%20%3D%20TPermission%3CAdminActions%2C%20AdminReasons%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20AdminPermissions%20extends%20Permissions%3CAdminActions%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20protected%20permissions%3A%20TAdminPermission%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(permissions%3A%20TAdminPermission%5B%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(permissions)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20UserActions%20%3D%20'Subscribe'%20%7C%20'Unsubscribe'%3B%0D%0Atype%20UserReasons%20%3D%20'AlreadySubscribed'%20%7C%20'AlreadyUnsubscribed'%3B%0D%0Atype%20TUserPermission%20%3D%20TPermission%3CUserActions%2C%20UserReasons%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20UserPermissions%20extends%20Permissions%3CUserActions%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20protected%20permissions%3A%20TUserPermission%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(permissions%3A%20TUserPermission%5B%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super(permissions)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20permissions%3A%20TUserPermission%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20action%3A%20'Subscribe'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20enabled%3A%20true%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20user%20%3D%20new%20UserPermissions(permissions)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Auser.hasPermission('Subscribe')%3B%20%2F%2F%20Valid%2C%20should%20return%20true%0D%0Auser.hasPermission('Unsubscribe')%3B%20%2F%2F%20Valid%2C%20should%20return%20false%0D%0Auser.hasPermission('Add%20User')%3B))

Comment: This is perfect! Exactly what I was looking for.